# Bash script echo error

Tags: bash

What is wrong in this code? I am just trying to write something from a function.

```
$ cat system_info.sh 

#!/bin/bash

drive_space ()
{
    echo "drive space"
}

$(drive_space)
```

Error message

```
$ ./system_info.sh 
./system_info.sh: line 8: drive: command not found
```

Comment: Just call using `drive_space`

Comment: thanks. can you explain why it worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$(command)` is *command substitution*. Bash expands it to the output of the command (similarly to `` `command` ``. In this case, the command's output is `drive space`, so bash tries to run it, but it can't find the `drive` command.

Command substitution is typically used when you need to capture the output in a variable:

```
output=$(drive_space)  # $output now contains "drive space".
```

To call a function, just use its name:

```
drive_space
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(drive_space)` executes `drive space` which isn't a command.

```
#!/bin/bash

drive_space ()
{
    echo "drive space"
}

drive_space
```